# Get ExitCode from Process in PowerShell While Redirecting StandardError

Tags: powershell, exit-code

I'm currently working on a PowerShell script that includes the line

`$process1 = Start-Process -FilePath ($exePath1) -PassThru -RedirectStandardError ($logPath1)`

Which starts a long-running process and redirects the process' StandardError to a log file. My problem is that this also apparently interferes with ExitCode.

```
$process1.ExitCode
```

returns null after the process has exited. If I remove "RedirectStandardError ($logPath1)" then ExitCode returns the value my dummy-program is expected to return.

Should I be doing something different? I'm hoping to be able to start the process (redirecting the StandardError to the log file for diagnostics), wait a few seconds to make sure it doesn't crash, and retrieve the ErrorCode in the event that it does.

Comment: use `$process1.WaitForExit()` firstly before obtaining the `$process1.ExitCode`.

Comment: @t0mm13b: I'm using $process1.HasExited. The process in question is very vulnerable to configuration mistakes, so I want to start it up and make sure that it didn't crash out.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to wait for the process and you're not running it as a different user:

```
$StartParams = @{
    FilePath = $exePath1
    RedirectStandardError = $logPath1
    PassThru = $True
    Wait = $True
}
$ReturnCode = (Start-Process @StartParams).ExitCode
```

Since it's long-running, here's an alternative method with PSJobs:

```
$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $StartParams = @{
        FilePath = $exePath1
        RedirectStandardError = $logPath1
        PassThru = $True
        Wait = $True
    }
    (Start-Process @StartParams).ExitCode
}
If ($Job.State -eq 'Completed')
{
    $ReturnCode = Receive-Job -Job $Job
}
```

Comment: Upvote for the "Wait" idea, but this unfortunately doesn't work for me since the process in question is long-lived; I can't have my script hang waiting for it to possibly error out.

Comment: Kick off a child script as a job to do this bit then?

Comment: This partially works although the behavior is... odd. First off, you can't access variables from an outer scope, so I had to pass them in. Now it launches my console app, but no output is written to the console even on a Flush. I know that it's working, but nothing is shown. The weirdest thing though, is that $Job.State -eq 'Completed' actually returns true, even though -Wait is included. $Job.Error returns null. Any thoughts?

Comment: Oh that's right. Make sure you include the $using scope or you have to pass them in as arguments. @dornadigital As to your other concerns, does your console app write to stdout? Might want to try launching a new window.  I assumed your exe was non-interactive considering how you're trying to run things.

Comment: Using   $Job = Start-Job -ArgumentList $exePath1, $logPath1 -ScriptBlock {
    invoke-expression ("cmd /c start powershell -Command {(Start-Process -FilePath '" + $args[0] + "' -RedirectStandardError '" + $args[1] + "' -PassThru -Wait).ExitCode}")
} launches everything as I'd expect, but I can't seem to access the ExitCode again. Receive-Job -Job $Job just returns null. Is this one of those speed and position problems, where you can know one but not the other?